# Extract data from thousands of Excel files into database

Tags: sql-server, excel, sharepoint

We use SharePoint 2013 as a library to hold thousands of Excel files, with almost never consistent formatting, to manage projects occurring on servers. Somewhere in these maybe formatted as table objects is a common set of server names.

Somehow, without being able to change this process in the short term, I need to pull data from all these files to identify how many projects are targeting a particular server.

I've got access to SQL Server 2016 enterprise, and wondering if something like PolyBase could help with this? I also wonder about SSIS but I don't expect any tables to look exactly like another one.

Other tools may be an option, but I'm not sure what can handle this scale and variety. I think daily updates to the data would be enough, but even so it's still a mess.

How do I pull thousands of varied excel tables into a database? Is this even possible?

Any longer term solution that doesn't allow them to format and annotate like excel is unlikely to actually be adopted.

Comment: If I understood your problem, this one seems to be a solution: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/76850/

Answer (score 0):

The less you know in advance, the more difficult it will be...

Some ideas:

#### Technology

- read about `FROM OPENROWSET` which allows to read from an Excel
- read about `linked server`
- Use Excel and its great abilities through VBA to iterate through all your Excel-Sheets, open them, analyse them and fill proper tables. Within Excel you know most about your messy data...

#### Target structure

- You might create thousands of tables, each representing one single sheet in all your Excel files. You could query these tables with dynamically created SQL (using meta-data of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`) or think about *Full-Text-Search*
- You might import each sheet into one single XML-structure (`SELECT * ... FOR XML PATH('...')`). In this case you'd need a target table with columns for Path and name of your Excel, Name of the sheet and an XML column for your data. Another approach was to represent each File on one XML and include all sheets there. Try to define common naming for all your data. Querying XML allows to query columns without knowing their actual names (`XQuery with XPath using *`).
- If your Excels are `xlsx` already, you might open them with UNZIP and take the existing XML *as-is*.

To be honest: I do not think that any tool can do the magic to import such a wide range of mess automatically...

Comment: Would something like Hadoop or another NoSQL repository help to dump them in first, and then define a schema when trying to read? Given the number of sheets and files, trying to manually review these would take months at a minimum.